# Laravel migrate rollback error, Data too long for column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I am using Laravel 5.3, and the migration is really awesome to control db development.

My question is when I change the column type from string to text, everything is working well. But after user save data which length longer than 255(varchar). Then my migrate can't rollback. It will say Data too long for my column. Would like to ask everyone how to solve this problem?

=========================================================

```
Schema::table('tbname', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->text('value')->change();
});

Schema::table('tbname', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->string('value')->change();
});
```

=========================================================

Seeder:

```
$records = [
    [
        'description' => 'The description is longer than 255. The description is longer than 255. The description is longer than 255. The description is longer than 255. The description is longer than 255. The description is longer than 255. The description is longer than 255. The description is longer than 255. The description is longer than 255. The description is longer than 255. The description is longer than 255. '
    ],
    [
        'description' => 'The description is longer than 255. The description is longer than 255. The description is longer than 255. The description is longer than 255. The description is longer than 255. The description is longer than 255. The description is longer than 255. The description is longer than 255. The description is longer than 255. The description is longer than 255. The description is longer than 255. '
    ]
];

foreach ($records as $index => $record) {
    Desc::create($record);
}
```

Comment: Need more details here. Please add the migration code and the table description from the DB to the question.

Comment: If you are using MySQL version < 5.7 then this error recently I was also come up with this error. You can find solution here

Comment: https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error

Comment: Any fix for this issue? I have the same exact issue on L5.4 during rollback.

Comment: @OmisakinOluwatobi I have updated my answer to provide a little more explanation, as well as a potential workaround.

Answer (score 11):

You have a `text` field that has more than 255 characters in it. In your rollback, you're attempting to change the field to `varchar(255)`. At this point, MySQL has a decision to make: either truncate the data to fit into 255 characters, or throw an error.

If using MySQL in strict mode, MySQL will throw an error. If not using strict mode, MySQL will truncate the data without error.

Laravel 5.3 was changed to use strict mode by default.

If you want to stop getting this error, you can disable strict mode by setting `'strict' => false` in your `config/database.php` file.

Please note that while this will suppress the error, there are consequences. The data that previously caused this error will now just be **truncated** without any error.

If you only want to disable strict mode for the rollback, you can create a second database connection with strict mode disabled, and the tell your migration to use that connection for the rollback. Remember, though, this will truncate all data in this field longer than 255 characters.

config:

```
'connections' => [
    'mysql' => [
        /* normal connection information */
        'strict' => true,
    ],
    'mysql-rollback' => [
        /* normal connection information */
        'strict' => false,
    ],
],
```

migration:

```
public function down()
{
    Schema::connection('mysql-rollback')->table('tbname', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('value')->change();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. In deed, a normal rollback from text to varchar is not useful in production. In development, I just dropped all the table and rerun the migration.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel string type create varchar column in database. and Values in VARCHAR columns are variable-length strings. The length can be specified as a value from 0 to 255 before MySQL 5.0.3, and 0 to 65,535 in 5.0.3 and later versions. The effective maximum length of a VARCHAR in MySQL 5.0.3 and later is subject to the maximum row size (65,535 bytes, which is shared among all columns) and the character set used.

Instead of using string use text datatype. because you are running mysql version less than  MySQL 5.0.3.

Comment: (65,535 bytes, which is shared among all columns)
You brightened my day!!